# Bitwise operation

Tags: java

there is 4 properties and each one of them can be activated.  To know which one is activated i receive an int value.  Using bitwise and operation i get 1, 2, 4 or 8 each number correspond to an activated property.

```
if((state & 1) == 1) {
status = 1;
                } else if ((state & 2) == 2) {
status = 2;
                } else if((state & 4) == 4) {
status = 4;
                } else if((state & 8) == 8) {
status = 8;
                }
```

I was wondering if could calculate status with one bitwise operation ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do what in one line of code? There are 4 different if statements there, to process each option. How can it be condensed in one line?

Comment: You can use no lines of code as this doesn't do anything.  You need to provide a more realistic example, much depends on what is in the blocks.

Comment: how can u think about putting 4 if in one single line????

Comment: I was wondering if i could get 1, 2, 4 or 8 in line of bitwise operation ?

Comment: If `state` can have any of those 4 bits set, why do you just check for one and set `status` to that? What I mean is: if `state` was 3, `status` would be 1 regardles of the second bit (2) being set or not. What's the purpose of this?

Answer (score 2):

If `state` always has exactly one of the four bits set, then your code is not very useful, as it is the same as

```
status = state;
```

If `state` can have any number of bits set, your code sets `status` to the least significant set bit in `state`. This can also be done with:

```
status = state & -state;
```

Comment: Brilliant binary operation. I think that is just what @xtrem06 wanted.